# Sort Array with NSRange in swift both by length and location

Tags: arrays, swift, sorting, nsrange

I am trying to sort an Array of NSRanges in swift both by length and location:

```
var allranges = [NSRange?]()
allranges.append(NSRange(location: 3, length: 5))
allranges.append(NSRange(location: 9, length: 2))
allranges.append(NSRange(location: 9, length: 1))
allranges.append(NSRange(location: 24, length: 5))
allranges.append(NSRange(location: 16, length: 9))
allranges.append(NSRange(location: 11, length: 6))

allranges.sortInPlace{ $0!.location < $1!.location && $0!.length < $1!.length}
print(allranges)
```

this is what I have printed:

[Optional((3,5)), **Optional((9,2)), Optional((9,1))**, Optional((24,5)), Optional((11,6)), Optional((16,9))]

but I want this instead:

[Optional((3,5)), **Optional((9,1)), Optional((9,2))**, Optional((24,5)), Optional((11,6)), Optional((16,9))]

please help!

Comment: Why do you declare a range as optional?

Comment: I am iterating allranges, and I need to make some indexes nil at some point...

Comment: OK, but your sort code will crash if there is a `nil` range...

Comment: got it! no nil range before sort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You presumably want to sort by `location`, and if `location` is the same, then sort by `length`, e.g.:

```
var allranges = [NSRange]()
allranges.append(NSRange(location: 3, length: 5))
allranges.append(NSRange(location: 9, length: 2))
allranges.append(NSRange(location: 9, length: 1))
allranges.append(NSRange(location: 24, length: 5))
allranges.append(NSRange(location: 16, length: 9))
allranges.append(NSRange(location: 11, length: 6))

allranges.sortInPlace { $0.location == $1.location ? $0.length < $1.length : $0.location < $1.location }
```